# Need help deploying my .NET MAUI application

Tags: android, github-actions, maui, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am attempting to deploy my .NET MAUI application integrated with Firebase using GitHub Actions for the deployment process.

I am encountering an issue during the publishing step of the workflow. The specific error message that I receive is as follows:

```
Run dotnet publish ProjetSport/ProjetSport/ProjetSport.csproj --framework net7.0-android --configuration Release --output ./publish/android
  dotnet publish ProjetSport/ProjetSport/ProjetSport.csproj --framework net7.0-android --configuration Release --output ./publish/android
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e ***0***
  env:
    DOTNET_ROOT: /home/runner/.dotnet
MSBuild version 17.6.1+8ffc3fe3d for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  ProjetSport -> /home/runner/work/GithubProjetSportMaui/GithubProjetSportMaui/ProjetSport/ProjetSport/bin/Release/net7.0-android/ProjetSport.dll
  Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
/home/runner/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Linux/33.0.46/tools/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2402,3):  

  error MSB4044: The "BuildApkSet" task was not given a value for the required parameter "KeyStore".  

 [/home/runner/work/GithubProjetSportMaui/GithubProjetSportMaui/ProjetSport/ProjetSport/ProjetSport.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

***This is what I did***

**-> My workflow at the root of my project on Github**

```
name: Deploy to Firebase App Distribution

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.8.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: '7.0.x'
  
    - name: Setup Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 16
        
    - name: Check current directory
      run: |
        echo "Current directory is"
        pwd
        echo "Directory content is"
        ls -a
        
    - name: Check ProjetSport directory
      run: ls -a ProjetSport
      
    - name: Install .NET Workloads
      run: dotnet workload install maui-android

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore ProjetSport/ProjetSport.sln 
      
    - name: Check Keystore File
      run: ls -la ProjetSport/

    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore ProjetSport/ProjetSport.sln
      env:
        KEYSTORE_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/My keystore file path....
        KEYSTORE_PASSWORD:  ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
        KEYSTORE_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_ALIAS }}
        KEY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
        

    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish ProjetSport/ProjetSport/ProjetSport.csproj --framework net7.0-android --configuration Release --output ./publish/android


    - name: Deploy to Firebase
      uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
      with:
        args: appdistribution:distribute publish/com.companyname.projetsport-Signed.apk
      env:
        FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON }}
        PROJECT_ID: My ProjectId FireBase
```

-> **My project .csproj file**

```
      <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
      <AndroidSigningKeyStore>$(KEYSTORE_PATH)</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
      <AndroidSigningStorePass>$(KEYSTORE_PASSWORD)</AndroidSigningStorePass>
      <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>$(KEYSTORE_ALIAS)</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
      <AndroidSigningKeyPass>$(KEY_PASSWORD)</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
```

*The confidential information was added to github's secret settings and it works.*

I would appreciate any advice on how to solve this deployment problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said you want to build it with Github actions? What exactly is the relevance of the Firebase part?

Comment: @TanakaMawere I only used this one, but maybe there are other solutions for deploying other than firebase.

Comment: Sorry. I am getting lost when you say 'deploying to firebase". Maybe I am not aware of deployment of a MAUI app to firebase.

Comment: @TanakaMawere Yes, it's normally possible to deploy a NET MAUI application on firebase. Except that I'm encountering an error that I don't understand because it's generic

Comment: How is “ MSB4044: The "BuildApkSet" task was not given a value for the required parameter "KeyStore"” generic?

Comment: @Jason This means that it can't find the keystore file I created at the root of my project using the "KeyTool" command.

Comment: I know nothing about firebase deployment, nor the contents of that workflow file, but if an error message mentions `required parameter "Keystore"`, I would ask myself whether somewhere in that file there should be a **parameter with that exact name,** "Keystore". Just a thought.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you, I've managed to solve the problem. Yes, you should have pointed directly to the file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to find a solution that involves explicitly specifying the path to my keystore file.

Here's how to do it:

-> In your .csproj file (located at the root of your project), rather than referencing the secrets that are stored on Github (the .csproj file doesn't have access to the contents of secrets inserted on Github), you must specify the actual data directly in clear

Here's what I did:

```
      <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
      <AndroidSigningKeyStore>$(KEYSTORE_PATH)</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
      <AndroidSigningStorePass>$(KEYSTORE_PASSWORD)</AndroidSigningStorePass>
      <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>$(KEYSTORE_ALIAS)</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
      <AndroidSigningKeyPass>$(KEY_PASSWORD)</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
```

**And here is the solution:**

```
      <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>  
  <AndroidSigningKeyStore>$(pwd)/NameProjet/file.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
      <AndroidSigningStorePass>password</AndroidSigningStorePass>
      <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>alias_name</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
      <AndroidSigningKeyPass>password</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
```

*The command "$(pwd)/ProjetSport/my-release-key.keystore" in the "AndroidKeyStore" field specifies the path to the keystore file, including the directory name.

*Please note that if you opt for this solution, your project must be defined as ***private***, as the information concerned is sensitive and must remain confidential.

Comment: Super! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/?_ga=2.105699459.1038351714.1685320442-530046372.1660608907) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.